# Progress Bar for conditional while loop using PysimpleGUI

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I am seeking to add a status bar showing the progress, but not been able to accomplish this,
Below is my code. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pandas as pd
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
from geopy.extra.rate_limiter import RateLimiter


sg.theme("DarkTeal2")
layout = [[sg.T("")], [sg.Text("Import file: "), sg.Input(), sg.FileBrowse(key="-IN-")],[sg.Button("Submit")], 
          [sg.Button("Exit")],[sg.ProgressBar(100, orientation= 'h' , size=(50, 10), key= 'progressbar' )]]

###Building Window
window = sg.Window('Geocoder', layout, size=(600,150))
progress_bar = window['progressbar']
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == "Submit":
        file = values["-IN-"]
        filename = file.split('/')[len(file.split('/'))-1]
        geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent = "geoapiExercises") 
        geocode = RateLimiter(geolocator.geocode, min_delay_seconds=1)
        df = pd.read_csv(filename, encoding = 'unicode_escape')
        df['location'] = df['add'].apply(geocode)
        df['Lat'] = df['location'].apply(lambda x: x.latitude if x else None)
        df['Lon'] = df['location'].apply(lambda x: x.longitude if x else None)
        df.to_csv('Geo_test.csv')      
        
    elif event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event=="Exit":
        break
    for i in range(1,10):
        progress_bar.update(i)
        i=i+=1
window.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So a few things.

First is that you can check out some of the demos on github if you haven't like this [one](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Progress_Meters.py). I am not up-to-date with the PySimpleGUI code, but seems like they are still using `.update_bar` like `progress_bar.update_bar(i)` to increment the values. Also I am unsure when exactly you want to update your progress bar, as currently it would not be triggered by any specific event but the `while` loop. My assumption is that you would like your code to update the progress bar while it executes some task like the lines in the `"Submit"` event. In that case, you would need to decide how you want to divide the 100 units of progress with any given code. For example:

```
if event == "Submit":
    progress_bar.update_bar(0, 100)

    file = values["-IN-"]
    filename = file.split('/')[len(file.split('/'))-1]

    progress_bar.update_bar(10, 100)

    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent = "geoapiExercises") 
    geocode = RateLimiter(geolocator.geocode, min_delay_seconds=1)

    progress_bar.update_bar(30, 100)

    df = pd.read_csv(filename, encoding = 'unicode_escape')
    df['location'] = df['add'].apply(geocode)

    progress_bar.update_bar(60, 100)

    df['Lat'] = df['location'].apply(lambda x: x.latitude if x else None)
    df['Lon'] = df['location'].apply(lambda x: x.longitude if x else None)
    df.to_csv('Geo_test.csv')      

    progress_bar.update_bar(100, 100)
```